# Start an interval task upon creating a Rails session (user logging in)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to basically create a scheduled task upon the user logging in. What Rails utility, gem, etc does this? Basically the Rails server needs to alert the browser user every two minutes, based on a set of conditions. This task has to end on sessions#destroy

In Sessions Controller

```
def new
 @user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session]  [:password])
if @user 
 session[:@user_id] = @user.id
 #how do i create a scheduled task for this session? I have a #current_user Application Controller method that will find #sessions[:@user_id] and identify it as the current user.

end
end


def destroy

sessions[:@user_id] = nil
#need to end scheduled task here.

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scheduled task?" Like a cron job?

Comment: I just mean that the Rails server is keeping track of time since login in an unending way, till log out. It does Time.now, and then every two minutes it alerts the user's browser.

Comment: I mean writing a function that calls itself every two minutes, but would this function still keep running after being started in sessions/new? I see how I could make it a method in the same controller itself now..

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to show an alert in the browser, in which case you'll need to use Javascript and not so much Rails. A javascript function can poll the server every X minutes and find out if conditions have been met for the browser action to fire?

Comment: I did not want the Javascript approach for this because I already use Angular to do a tonne of clientside things, and I have had situations where all the if/else statements throw Angular out of loop and not running sometimes. I just got a delicate balance right now that works, and this is something running every two minutes so there is a chance it will interfere with my other Angular updates.

Comment: Nevertheless I did find the solution for me that should work (a Rails recursive function that checks if current_user is there first). I will update with my own answer shortly, may not have time today.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want in Rails, you could use a [Thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html).

```
# create thread

my_thread = Thread.new do

  # do some junk

  # put thread to sleep for 120 seconds

  sleep(120)
end

# nuke the thread on session#destroy

my_thread.kill
```

Comment: Won't this be a nightmare to debug?

Comment: @ConstantM Any time you involve threads, you are opening a can of (concurrency) worms. It *could* be a nightmare to debug, but that depends on how simple or complex OP wants to make the code in the thread. I personally avoid threads whenever possible, but threading does address OP's concerns within his specifications. The specific implementation details are beyond the scope of my answer and SO in general.

Comment: I reckon the are better ways to solve the problem than using threads. This shouldn't be needed if following Rails conventions. But yes, you did answer the question. :)

Comment: @ConstantM I'd be happy to see an alternative.

Comment: As said in a previous comment, Javascript polling would probably be better suited.

Comment: @ConstantM I wouldn't use polling (or maybe I'm not following your use of the term 'polling'). I'd use setInterval(), since OP wants to perform an action at a regular interval and not based on some condition. Anyhow, this is becoming a bit of an extended conversation, which hopefully, can still be of interest to others down the line.

Comment: Yes, using setInterval() is exactly what I meant. :)

Comment: @ConstantM I see -- there's the confusion. setInterval() isn't polling anything.

Comment: If you're using setInterval() to poll the server with a GET every two minutes, you are indeed polling something. A server, every two minutes.